# how to put python script into jetson nano startup?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nano, nvidia-jetson

The program should run on boot. the `nano` operating system `(jet-pack)` not allowing the auto-login too. I tried to put the script into its startup file but the program doesn't boot.

Comment: Please help us help you. What have you tried?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Run you script in cron job.

```
sudo crontab -e

* * * /usr/bin/python my_script.py
```

This will make your script run on boot.

Kindly provide complete paths in script to run error-free

Comment: this would run the script every minute and not only on boot. Use @reboot instead.